# 1and1: Unable to host an external domain

Tags: web-hosting, looking-for-hosting, shared-hosting, 1and1

I'm sorry if this isn't the right place for this question, but I'm presently having difficulties with my hosting provider ([1and1](http://www.1and1.co.uk)). Two weeks ago, two of my clients bought hosting from them on my recommendation, but as it turned out, 1and1 are having severe technical difficulties.

Right now non of their hosting packages are able to accept ANY external domains. So either you pay the costs of transferring the registrar of your domain, or you use the ugly 1and1 domain name. Not any good for a hosting company of 1and1's reputation!

They have been promising me for two weeks that they're going to fix the problem, but as you have probably guessed by now, that hasn't been the case.

I would like to know if a) Anyone else is in the same boat as me, and b) If there are other comparably reputable hosting providers that I should consider moving to instead?

Very disappointing! :(

Note: This is for 1and1 **in the UK**. I imagine it isn't affecting users in other countries(?)

---

**Clarification**: 1and1 are unable to accept ANY external domains. That means that even if you update your DNS details on your domain, their system cannot be updated to add your external domain to your account.

Comment: "1and1's reputation"... I guess you mean their marketing efforts, as I've never had a good experience with 1&1's limited, convoluted hosting options. As for an additional host, there are lots out there.

Comment: Actually I've never heard anything bad about them before, and their hosting is one of the most fully featured that I've ever seen. (How many shared hosting companies allow you enough power to serve static content, for example?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems 1and1 have finally resolved this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to transfer the registrar. But you need to host your DNS records on their name servers. Otherwise (for whatever reason) they cannot link the web hosting package with domain name. At least that was the situation 2 years ago when I did this myself.

1) Find out what name servers you should use from 1and1 control panel (sorry, I cannot give you precise instructions as I no longer have such type of hosting with them -- only full dedicated server -- which may actually work in the same way but I do not have login details at home (and don't really want to mess around myself without the need)).

2) Go to control panel of your domain name (your registrar, where you currently hosting your domain name) and change DNS servers.

If you do #2 first and #1 few hours later (I dunno, 2-6 hours maybe) 1and1 should pick up and setup domain names very quickly. Otherwise there may be delays up to few days (when I did this myself over 2 years ago I had to wait like 2 or 3 days -- don't remember exact reason for a delay).

1&1 should have FAQ or manual on how to do this (at least I remember reading something like that). Otherwise contact their support for exact instructions.

Comment: I guess I haven't made myself clear. Updating the DNS is **not** going to help by itself. 1and1 also have to add the domain to their records for them to know which site to route it to. At present that functionality is broken, meaning you have two choices: Change registrar or use the ugly URL.

Comment: _"1and1 also have to add the domain to their records for them to know which site to route it to"_ -- that's exactly what hosting DNS on their servers will do. _"At present that functionality is broken"_ -- I see. I guess I have misread your description. My apologies.